# Using lapply to group list of data frames by column

Tags: r, list, dataframe, group-by, lapply

I have a list that contains multiple data frames. I would like to sort the data by Category (`A`) and sum the Frequencies (`B`) using the `lapply`-command.

The data is `df_list`

```
df_list
$`df.1`

        A       B
1   Apples      2
2   Pears       5
3   Apples      6
4   Pears       1
5   Apples      3


$`df.2`
        A       B
1   Oranges     2
2   Pineapples  5
3   Oranges     6
4   Pineapples  1
5   Oranges     3
```

The desired outcome df_list_2 looks like this:

```
df_list_2
$`df.1`

        A       B
1   Apples      11
2   Pears       6       

$`df.2`
        A       B
1   Oranges     11
2   Pineapples  6
```

I have tried the following code based on lapply:

```
df_list_2<-df_list[, lapply(B, sum), by = A]
```

However, I get an error code, saying that `A` was not found.

Either I mistake how the lapply command works in this case or my understating of how it should work is flawed. 
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you've picked some details up from data.table in your code but haven't referenced it here. What you've done is halfway to a data.table solution so if that's what you're after, you'll need to specify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `aggregate` in `lapply`

```
lapply(df_list, function(x) aggregate(B~A, x, sum))

#[[1]]
#       A  B
#1 Apples 11
#2  Pears  6

#[[2]]
#           A  B
#1    Oranges 11
#2 Pineapples  6
```

---

Using `map` from `purrr` and `dplyr` it would be

```
library(dplyr)
purrr::map(df_list, ~.x %>% group_by(A) %>% summarise(sum = sum(B)))
```

**data**

```
df_list <- list(structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), 
.Label = c("Apples", "Pears"), class = "factor"), B = c(2L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")), 
structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Oranges", 
"Pineapples"), class = "factor"), B = c(2L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")))
```

Answer (score 1):

I fear you might not have a clear idea of `lapply` nor the extract operator (`[`).  Remember `lapply(list, function)` applies the specified `function` you give it to each element of the `list` you give it. Extract gives you the element you specify:

```
x <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
x[2]
## "b"
```

I would imagine that somewhere in your R workspace you have an object names `B` which is why you didn't get an error along the lines of

```
## Error in lapply(B, sum) : object 'B' not found
```

Conversely if you had (accidentally or intentionally) defined both `A` and `B` you would see the error

```
## Error in df_list[, lapply(B, sum), by = A] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

because that's not at all how to use `[`; remember, you just pass indexes or booleans to `[` along with the occasional optional argument, but `by` is not one of those.

So without further adieu, here's how I would do this (in base R):

```
# make some data
a <- c(1, 2, 1, 2, 1)
b <- c(2, 5, 6, 1, 3)
df_list <- list(df.1 = data.frame(A = c('Apples', 'Pears')[a], B = b), 
                df.2 = data.frame(A = c('Oranges', 'Pineapples')[a], B = b))

# simplify it
df_list_2 <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {
    aggregate(list(B = x$B), list(A = x$A), sum)
})

# the desired result
df_list_2

## $df.1
##        A  B
## 1 Apples 11
## 2  Pears  6
## 
## $df.2
##            A  B
## 1    Oranges 11
## 2 Pineapples  6
```

You can take advantage of the fact that a `data.frame` is just a list and shorten up your code like this:

```
df_list_2 <- lapply(df_list, function(x) {
    aggregate(x['B'], x['A'], sum)
})
```

but the first way of writing it should help make more clear what we're doing

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain what is going on, Andy. That was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` syntax in OP's post can changed to

```
library(data.table)
lapply(df_list, function(x) as.data.table(x)[, .(B = sum(B)), by = A])
#$df.1
#        A  B
#1: Apples 11
#2:  Pears  6

#$df.2
#            A  B
#1:    Oranges 11
#2: Pineapples  6
```

#### data

```
df_list <- list(df.1 = structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("Apples", "Pears"), class = "factor"), B = c(2L, 
5L, 6L, 1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5")), df.2 = structure(list(A = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Oranges", "Pineapples"), class = "factor"), 
    B = c(2L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5")))
```